# What does -> mean in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've seen that in spree commerce.

```
go_to_state :confirm, if: ->(order) { order.confirmation_required? }
```

So what'll do that symbol?

Comment: I've searched in google but shows no relevent result

Comment: Use the search box in this site. Search `[ruby] "->"` or whatever other operator you're wondering about.

Comment: Looks like the notation for a `lambda`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a *lambda literal*. Check this example:

```
 > plus_one = ->(x){x+1}
 => #<Proc:0x9fbaa00@(irb):3 (lambda)> 
 > plus_one.call(3)
 => 4
```

A lambda literal is a constructor for [Proc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Proc.html). A `Proc` is a way to have a block of code assigned to a variable. After this, you can call your block of code again, with different arguments, as many times as you wish.

This is how you can pass a "function" as parameter in ruby. In many languages, you could pass a reference to a function. In ruby, you can pass a Proc object.

Answer (score 6):

In Ruby 1.9 you can use the stab operator `->` to create a lambda.

```
l1 = lambda { puts "I'm a lambda" }
l2 = -> { puts "I'm a lambda" }
```

The operator also accept arguments.

```
l1 = lambda(name) { puts "I'm a #{name}" }
l2 = ->(name) { puts "I'm a #{name}" }
```